# How can I join 3 tables and total the column from one of the tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Im having 3 tables.
(Just for example have taken numbers originally i have taken some short names)

1. table1 as 1
2. table2 as 2
3. table3 as 3

block_id is the connecting attribute for all the three tables

notes:

- block_id is unique,block_status exists in table1
- duplicate block_id's, thickness_id, no_of_slabs exists in table2
- duplicate block_id's, sub_block_id's,p_status exists in table3

I want to display block_id, total number of slabs,p_status for respective block_id's where status='cut'

- we can get total number of slabs from table through block_id
- if all the sub_block_id's status are completed then z_status=fullyCompleted else partiallyCompleted.

I have tried the below query which it is not working,

```
select 1.block_id,sum(2.noofslabs) as totalslabs,if(3.status='completed','fullyCompleted','partiallyCompleted') from table1 as 1 
left join table2 as 2 on 1.block_id=2.block_id 
left join table3 as 3 on 1.block_id=3.block_id where 1.status='Cut'
```

If im not adding the table3, the result of totalslabs are correct, if I am adding joining table3, the result is wrong. 
One more thing is how to get that z_status as partiallycompleted or fully completed

Comment: And what does "result is getting wrong" mean? Are you missing a `GROUP BY` or does the sum get doubled/tripled/whatever? You know how joins work? My glass orb is broken.

Comment: i have given group by in the original running query.

Comment: when i join table 3 the sum is getting wrong result, it is getting show high values after adding table3

Comment: If only I could downvote you twice. This is the second time you say "but in the original query it's different". Post the damn query and sample data and desired result, otherwise we can't help you! And the higher values are caused by joins. Learn how joins work, read about distinct and if all that doesn't help...like I said, post the required information!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use numbers as table aliases. Use a name which starts with a letter.

```
select t1.block_id,sum(t2.noofslabs) as totalslabs,if(t3.status='completed','fullyCompleted','partiallyCompleted') from table1 as t1 
left join table2 as t2 on t1.block_id=t2.block_id 
left join table3 as t3 on t1.block_id=t3.block_id where t1.status='Cut'
```

should work

Comment: Oh, and whenever you get an error message, post the error message.

Comment: just for example i have taken numbers. originally im taking some short names